# Randomly replace 2 values in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Good day,

First of all, I've seen many posts on this site that deal with similar problems, yet none of them offered a working solution. I'd highly appreciate if you'd take the time to at look my question before referring to another post.

I've been spending a few hours trying to figure out a simple way to replace two items in dictionary in a way that would take the items from two randomly selected pair of keys and switch between the two. such as:

```
dictionary1 = {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C'}
dictionary2 = {'a':'B', 'b':'A', 'c':'C'}
```

Now, I understand that dictionaries don't have indexes, which makes the process a bit tricky. So I've built this function:

```
def get_neighbor (dictionary1 ):
    dictionary1 = dictionary1 
    def keys_with_value(self, value):
        return [k for k, v in list(self.items()) if v == value]
    copy = {}
    copy = dictionary1 
    letter1 = random.choice(list(copy))
    letter2 = random.choice(list(copy))

    key1 =  (keys_with_value(copy,letter1))[0]
    key2 =  (keys_with_value(copy,letter2))[0]
    copy[key1] = letter2
    copy[key2] = letter1
    return copy
```

As you can see, the function takes dictionary1 and creates a copy. Then the function reassigns the keys and values of 2 randomly chosen letters.

Yet, when I'm trying to look into the function it appears that **the end result effects BOTH the original (dictionary1) and the copy (dictionary2).**

It seems as if both dictionaries are stored in the same place. But that's impossible, right?

I would highly appreciate any help/suggestion you guys (and girls) might provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems as if both dictionaries are stored in the same place. But
>   that's impossible, right?

Actually, that's exactly what's happening. Your line:

```
copy = dictionary1
```

makes `copy` another name for the object already named `dictionary1`. It does not create a new dictionary containing the contents of `dictionary1`.

Python variables are names for objects. Setting one variable equal to another assigns the name to the object, it does not copy the object. There are various ways to do that - for one way to do a shallow copy, you can use:

```
copy.update(dictionary1)
```

Or, as [Red Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2817371/red-alert) noted in the comments above, `copy = dictionary1.copy()`. That's better than declaring a new empty dict and using `update`.

Or, for more safety, use the `copy.deepcopy` function. With the example you've shown here there would be no difference, but if your dictionary had lists or other mutable objects as values the shallow copy would copy references to the objects rather than new objects.

Some notes on mutable vs. immutable objects follow, based on the comments thread:

It is common for implementations of Python (including the only one I can talk about with accuracy, the common C implementation) to reuse objects for some immutable objects. For example, the following code in C Python will result in two references to the same object:

```
x = 7
y = 7
```

Because `7` is immutable, it is safe to do this. You can subsequently rebind `x` to a different object, eg:

```
x = 9
```

This does not affect the shared object for `7`, and `y` will not change. This behavior is not special to immutable objects - `x = 9` rebinds the name in the same way that `x = [1, 2]` would. In neither case would `y` be affected. What is special is the behavior of mutable objects - code like `x = [1, 2]; x.append(3)` changes the underlying object. Correct Python implementations will not reuse objects for mutable classes.

In general, you will not have to care about this implementation detail. Although it is true that `x = 7; y = 7; x is y` will return `True` in the C implementation of Python, code should not rely on this. Instead, it is best to write your code as if it were entirely possible that `x` and `y` would have different objects - you can't mutate those objects, so it should never matter. Instead, use the comparison functions like `==` - those work regardless of the implementation detail. And in fact numeric equality can easily be true in cases where object identity is not, such as `x = 7; y = 7.0; x == y`.

All you actually have to worry about is whether you have other names for your mutable objects, such as:

```
x = [1, 2]
y = x
y.append(3)
```

Python variables are always references to objects, but in some cases you can work with the objects as if they were values. They aren't, but when you're doing things that are safe to do on shared objects (such as everything you can do to an integer) you don't have to care.

The one fly in this ointment is `None`. `None` is a singleton object - `None` is in fact a reference to a single immutable instance of `NoneType`. But because comparison logic can be written incorrectly, the correct way to check for `None` values is in fact to rely on that singleton nature and use `x is None` instead of `x == None` and run the risk that `x`'s equality check returns a false positive. I haven't checked the implementation details to see if it's even theoretically possible to create a second object of `NoneType`, but in any case nothing does.

You should make sure that when you are mutating an object, you either intend your mutations to affect all references to that object or that you make a copy first. Because it is impossible to mutate an immutable type like an `int`, you don't have to worry about this with `int`s, `tuple`s, `frozenset`s, or other built-in immutable types.

Comment: you talk about variables being assigned to objects, while this does not holds true for simple types like `int`. You shall correct your answer and instead of `variable` make sure you mention dict (and possibly lists).

Comment: @JanVlcinsky - in my opinion, the implementation details that values for simple immutable types such as `int` may have a shared object are irrelevant here. Yes, `x = 7; y = 7` may result in `x` and `y` having the same address while `x = []; y = []` will not - but the point that `x = []; y = x` does something altogether different from `x = []; y = []` is the main point.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would've never have figure it out.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Sorry, but you are touching very sensitive topic in Python and you insist on providing partially wrong statement. You tak about variables in Python in general being assigned by reference while this is true only to some types. The OP shall learn, that dict or list assigned will share the object, while doing the same for simple type is safe.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky - `7` is an object of type `int`, as a simple `type(7)` call will show you. `x = 7` binds the name `x` to an object, exactly as I described. Because that object is immutable, it is safe for an implementation to reuse the same object for all references to `7` - but that does not change the fact that `x` is a reference to an object. It looks to me like you are describing the difference between a mutable and immutable object as if it were a difference in whether a variable is a reference to an object or whether a variable "holds a value".

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks for a lesson about variables being references to objects. Yes, your statement "Settings one variable equal to another assigns the name to the object, it dos not copy the object.". But does that mean, that poor shults will not always use some deep or shallow copy, even when using immutable types? I hope not and it would be great, if you mention this important difference in your answer. The reason is "as dict is mutable type, changes of object content is possible, happens in place, and apply to all variables referring to that object."

Comment: I would say when dealing with immutable types to keep in mind that what you usually care about is value equality, not object identity. What matters after `x = 7; y = 7` is whether `x == y`, not whether `x is y`. `7 == 7.0` returns `True`, while `7 is 7.0` returns False. Basically, if it matters to your code that your references to immutable objects are actually references to the same object (outside the special case of the `None` singleton) you're doing something odd. And if you're not sure why you're doing it, you might be doing it wrong. But I'll put a note about immutables in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `random.sample` instead of `random.choice`. When you use `random.sample` you specify how many items you want and are guaranteed that you will not get the same letter twice. There is no such guarantee if you are using `random.choice` twice. Of course, if you don't mind it occasionally switching a value with itself (i.e nothing happening), then you do not need to change anything.

Here's how you could use `random.sample`:

```
letter1, letter2 = random.sample(copy, 2)
```

---

Also, when you are determining the keys to swap

```
key1 =  (keys_with_value(copy,letter1))[0]
key2 =  (keys_with_value(copy,letter2))[0]
```

you are looking for values that match the keys `letter1` and `letter2`. If you want `letter1` and `letter2` to hold values from `dictionary1`, you should use

```
letter1, letter2 = random.sample(copy.values(), 2)
```

---

Looking at your code some more, it seems to me that your `keys_with_values` function is entirely unnecessary. Simply finding two random keys and switching their values can be done like this:

```
key1, key2 = random.sample(copy, 2)
copy[key1], copy[key2] = copy[key2], copy[key1]
```

However, if you really did intend to for `letter1` and `letter2` to be keys, then you are switching the values of two keys that have values that are also keys. In that case, you can use

```
key1, key2 = random.sample([k for k, v in copy.items() if v in copy], 2)
copy[key1], copy[key2] = copy[key2], copy[key1]
```

Comment: Thanks for addressing ways to improve the random selection/update part rather than getting bogged down in object reference details.